# Upgrade Subversion 1.6 to 1.7 on CentOS? (can't find yum repository)

Tags: svn, centos, yum

I want to upgrade my SVN Server from 1.6 to 1.7. Unfortunately I can't find anything on the internet how to do this with yum. I have checked *rpmforge-extras* but it has only svn 1.6 and not 1.7

I wanted to update with yum because this is the most secure way for me. I'm not an experienced Linux user.

Is there a yum repository that contains 1.7 (subversion.x86_64 0:1.7.xxxxx.el5.rfx)?

If there is none, perhaps a short explanation how to update with just step by step.

Answer (score 20):

You could just build from the sources.

The following worked for me (although you may not want to do the update or install every package in "Development tools" and "Additional Development"):

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
sudo yum groupinstall "Additional Development"
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-1.7.8.tar.gz
tar zxvf subversion-1.7.8.tar.gz
cd subversion-1.7.8
./get-deps.sh
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

On my system this seems to put the binary in /usr/local/bin/svn whereas the 1.6 binary is in /usr/bin/svn so you might need set up an alias.

Comment: configure --prefix /usr 

will direct the make install to /usr/bin/svn

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a solution http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#centos I haven't tried it but it is officially supported http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#centos

Comment: "Officially supported"? What do you mean by that? From the top of that page: "The Apache Subversion project does not officially endorse or maintain any binary packages of the Subversion software."

Comment: I simply mean that it is mentioned on apache.org and not a back water project that no one know about.

Comment: The WANdisco packages are supported in that we have compiled and fully tested them before release, and we are around to help on the SVN forum  (http://www.svnforum.org/forum.php) if needed.

Answer (score 5):

I used the rpmforge repository:
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

After having installed the rpm-forge package, I installed subversion 1.7 by issuing this command:

sudo  yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras subversion

Completely painless upgrade.

Comment: You might need to install rpmforge repository. You can do it using this guide: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge. I wasn't able to download the rpmforge's .rpm package from using wget for some reason and had to use browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this to upgrade your subversion :

For CentOS/RHEL 7 Users:

```
[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

For CentOS/RHEL 6 Users:

```
[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

For CentOS/RHEL 5 Users:

```
[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/5/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Next you create a repo for your subversion:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/wandisco-svn.repo
```

Copy paste which one repo you used to `wandisco-svn.repo` file.

Then optionally, but advised, add the repository gpg signature:

```
wget http://opensource.wandisco.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco
gpg --quiet --with-fingerprint ./RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco
rpm --import ./RPM-GPG-KEY-WANdisco
```

And finally execute this below :

```
yum clean all
yum remove subversion
yum install epel-release
yum install subversion
```

Don't forget to use your root access to do that. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can download the binary packages from our website [here](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#centos).

Alternatively you can use [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/download), which supports 1.6.18 and 1.7.5, along with all the other stuff you need to get up and running (Apache, Tomcat, user admin etc).